# Skybox seams in OpenGL

Tags: vb.net, opengl

Can anyone tell me out how remove the seams in the skybox implementation I have here:

source code:

http://openglviewcontroller.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

I've been trying GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE to no avail.

Comment: without more details, (picture of what you're seeing, actual texture setup in the question...) it's hard to help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` on both `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` *and* `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`, usually near texture creation for clarity:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Also, you seem to be assuming `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_*` comes along for the ride when you bind another texture; this is not the case.  It's an aspect of a particular texture object's state, not the GL state as a whole.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution to the main problem. The other problem was the cubemap I was using had been resized badly so the colours had bled into each other at the edges. Cheers